# Full width bar with text

Tags: graphics, color, positioning

I'm trying to create a title page with this style [image: title page]

and put text in the purple bar. Every time that i try to make those bars with colorbox it gets centered and not full width like those. I'm trying to search over the internet how to make those bars and i found nothing yet. I don't wanna someone to do it for me, i just wanna a guide to know where to start.

Comment: Hello! Can you post a minimal example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/172164)) of what you've already tried? It will be much easier for people to help you when they can see the code you're using.

Comment: Is the document for print? Will it be printed professionally with bleed? Or do you just want the content to go to the edge of the page on screen and don't care if there is a white border when you print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `tikz` solution that should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\title{My Document Title}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=10mm, outer sep=0pt]
  \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west)
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
  \node (title) [fill=violet, anchor=north, text width=\paperwidth-10mm,
    align=center, font=\sffamily\Huge, text=white, minimum height=50mm]
    at ([yshift=-30mm]current page.north) {
      \@title \\[5mm]
      \LARGE\@author \\[5mm]
      \large\@date};
  \fill[violet] ([xshift=5mm, yshift=-5mm]title.south west) rectangle
    ++(\paperwidth, -15mm);
  \fill[violet] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth, 10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Welcome back after some gap